# Spring data jpa, how to filter and then sort results in this example?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I wrote a method, but as you can see - Category here is never used.

Is to possible to find only Dishes where Category is same as defined and only after it - sort it by parameter using plain Spring data jpa?
Or  the only way to it is a custom query?

```
public List<Dish> findAllDishesSorted(String sortField, String sortDirection, String category) {
    Sort sort = sortDirection.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name())
            ? Sort.by(sortField).ascending() : Sort.by(sortField).descending();

            return dishRepository.findAll(sort);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a method like below to your `DishRepository` and it should be able to achieve that without needing to write custom query with `@Query()` annotation

```
public interface DishRepository extends CrudRepository<Dish, Long> {
    Dish findByCategory(String category, Sort sort);
}
```